# Oauth Authentication for SharePoint REST API

Tags: rest, oauth, token, microsoft-graph

Based on my research and this [Video](https://youtu.be/IntbgqDNeNU?t=1645), 
I was under the impression that switching between the Graph API and the SharePoint REST API should be pretty straight forward.

- After obtaining an OAuth2 token, I am able to access the Graph API with a call such as:
  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives`.
- However calling the SharePoint Api as [documented](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service):
  `http://<my_tenant>/site/_api/lists`
  fails with:

  ```
  {"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."}
  ```

Is a different token required for the REST API? How can I acquire it?

Comment: there is a `authentication.asmx` soap endpoint which has `login` method, which returns a access token that can be further used while session lasts. Will that help?

Comment: Thank you  Swayam Siddha, I tried your approach, but was unable to login with my normal credentials.
Using python:

`from zeep import Client`

`client = Client('https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx?WSDL')`
client.service.Login(username='<my_user>@<mysite>.onmicrosoft.com', password='<my password>')

returns:

{
    'CookieName': None,
    'ErrorCode': 'PasswordNotMatch',
    'TimeoutSeconds': 0
}
And I have checked and double checked that the credentials are correct.

Comment: Your implementation seems alright. Cant help mate

Comment: You should check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297049/is-it-possible-to-use-app-only-graph-api-tokens-with-sharepoint-rest-api

Answer (score 3):

As of this moment, access to SharePoint endpoint via Graph API is possible only through the beta endpoint.

Your URL should be as below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/tenantname.sharepoint.com/lists
```

Make a normal GET call to the above endpoint, the output would be as below:

[image]

Reference - [Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint)

To access the `http://<my_tenant>/site/_api/lists` endpoint, Graph API token wont work.

If you are logged into SharePoint you don't need any token at all to make a get request (pure client-side solution). When you make the below call, it gets the data based on your permissions.

```
$.ajax({
           url: "https://sitecollectionurl/_api/web/lists",
           method: "GET",
           headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
           success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
          },
          error: function (data) {
              console.log("sowmthing went wrong: "+ data);
         }
});
```

Also, you can use the excellent Graph explorer to test your Graph API calls.
Here, select the version as beta and you can see the data from your sharepoint lists.

[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Answer (score -1):

If there is a 401-Error on request (test in browser)
the error includes detailed information about the authentication you need.